# Node JS: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

Am trying to start the server,
but i get this error

```
/home/ceddy/syd/sydjs/node_modules/keystone/admin/server/middleware/logError.js:7
    var msg = `[${endpoint}]`;
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
at Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/ceddy/syd/sydjs/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:138:7)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.createDynamicRouter (/home/ceddy/syd/sydjs/node_modules/keystone/admin/server/app/createDynamicRouter.js:65:21)
at createApp (/home/ceddy/syd/sydjs/node_modules/keystone/server/createApp.js:63:72)
at [object Object].initExpressApp (/home/ceddy/syd/sydjs/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/initExpressApp.js:5:46)
at [object Object].start (/home/ceddy/syd/sydjs/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/start.js:47:7)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ceddy/syd/sydjs/keystone.js:94:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

When i look at the file that seems to be causing the error on line 7 i don't see anything wrong like the console says... 
 Am i missing anything here, what's the cause please?
Thanks in advance

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
res.logError = function logError(endpoint, description, err) {
    if (arguments.length === 2 && typeof description !== 'string') {
        err = description;
        description = null;
    }
    var msg = `[${endpoint}]`;
    msg += description ? (` ${description}:`) : ' error:';
    if (err) {
        console.log(msg, err.message, '\n' + err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log(msg);
    }
};
next();
};
```

Comment: What version of Node are you running? You may not have support for template strings.

Comment: When i run $ nodejs --version i get v4.2.3 but when i run $ node --version i get v0.12.7
Which is which, thanks @ndugger

Comment: Well are you running the server with `node` or `nodejs`?

Comment: am running it with node @ben-fortune

Comment: Then run it with `nodejs`...

Comment: wtf!!! it worked, i didn't know that you can also run with nodejs, am a beginner hope you understand. thanks in advance, if you could post the your answer i mark it. @ben-fortune

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Syntax you trying to use is the part of new ES2015 standard. Make sure you use node version which supports [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

I suggest at least node 4.2.3 because it's LTS version and no iojs because it's merged back to node.

Comment: but when i run $ nodejs --version i see v.4.2.3